# Litmus test to ask mod to migrate my question to another SE site?

Tags: discussion

I just posted this question: [File naming conventions for `.cron` and `.systemd` extensions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020411/file-naming-conventions-for-cron-and-systemd-extensions?noredirect=1#comment1656676_1020411).

Then I started to wonder: *"Is AU the right site for this question?"* After all the last question I commented on a person was asking for a `dbus` command he could issue in `gnome-terminal` to find out if his computer was sleeping.

Probably 1/2 the questions here in AU are about wifi not working, bluetooth not working, mouse, keyboard, nvidia, radeon, brightness, sound, partitions, windows dual boot, UEFI, etc. that for lack of a better word are rudimentary.

**Does my question go overboard for AU and fail the litmus test meaning I should ask a mod to migrate it?**

Comment: Setting aside the part about it being overboard, why would you need a mod to migrate it? The question is posted by you, and has no answers, so you can simply delete and repost it wherever you want. No need for a mod to intervene.

Comment: Your question is fine. There are, of course, questions about things like fixing nonworking devices, but we also like questions about generic Linux stuff that applies to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, [as muru said](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17791/litmus-test-to-ask-mod-to-migrate-my-question-to-another-se-site#comment37270_17791), there is never a reason to ask a mod to migrate your own question. Just delete and repost. That's easier, cleaner and will make your question appear as new on the target site.

That said, your question is on topic here and welcome to stay.